# Partial derivatives turning into regular derivative

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative

If $z=z(x,y)$, and $x=x(t),y=y(t)$, write down the expression for $\frac{dz}{dx}$.
I am confused by the difference between partial and regular derivatives when they are used together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that 
$$dz=\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}dx+\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}dy$$
$$\implies \frac{dz}{dx}=\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\cdot \frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\cdot \frac{dy}{dt}\cdot \frac{dt}{dx}$$
$$\implies \frac{dz}{dx}=\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\cdot \frac{\frac{dy}{dt}}{\frac{dx}{dt}}$$

Tell me if you don't get the first line.

Comment: Yes, I am new to this and I don't understand the first line.

Comment: Read the part on *Total Differential* from this link ... http://www.solitaryroad.com/c353.html

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: I have just noticed that I was actually asked for $\frac{dz}{dt}$. Should I just divide the total differential by $dt$?

Comment: Yes, you need that only.